# Can the Source0 in a RPM Spec be a git repo?

Tags: git, rpm, rpm-spec

I want to build a rpm of my project automated.
So when I push a new tag to my git repo, it should build a rpm from this tag revision.
My problem is, how can I prep the sources and specify it in the RPM Spec file?

Is it possible to specify the git repo directly? Like:
    Source0: git://myserver/mygit.git

But what when I want to have the git repo available via https?

Any hints are appreciated! :)

Cheers,
Thilo

Comment: Have you tried doing that, what's the output/error do you get ?

Answer (score 7):

No. The URL in SourceX is being completely ignored by rpmbuild. Rpmbuild just take the basename and expect it to be present in %{_topdir}/SOURCES/

If you want to create RPM from your git archive easily then please check [mock-scm](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/mock/wiki/Plugin-Scm) or [Tito](https://github.com/dgoodwin/tito/).